# svg animation point pulse

Tags: animation, svg

im trying to make a pulsing SVG animation. You can see it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/z2Cm9/

```
<g transform="translate(0,0)">
    <polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="9.5,9.583 24.5,36 39.5,9.75"/>

    <animateMotion path="M 0,0 0,10 z" fill="freeze" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateMotion>
</g>

<g>
    <polyline fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="0,48.5 24.75,48.5 50,48.5 " >

        <animate 
        id="animation1"
        attributeName="points"
        from="0,48.5 24.75,48.5 50,48.5" 
        to="20,48.5 24.75,48.5 30,48.5"
        dur="0.5s"
        />

        <animate 
        id="animation2"
        attributeName="points"
        from="20,48.5 24.75,48.5 30,48.5"
        to="0,48.5 24.75,48.5 50,48.5" 
        begin="animation1.end"
        dur="0.5s"
        />

        <animate 
        id="animation3"
        attributeName="points"
        from="0,48.5 24.75,48.5 50,48.5" 
        to="20,48.5 24.75,48.5 30,48.5"
        begin="animation2.end"
        dur="0.5s"
        />

    </polyline>


</g>
```

As you can see it pulsates only once now. I want the movement of the line on the bottom to repeat. But cant seem to find a way to do this nicely. Is it for instance possible to add more then one stage. Like from, to, to etc?

Hope I asked the right way this time.

greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so?

```
    <animate 
        id="animation1"
        attributeName="points"
        from="0,48.5 24.75,48.5 50,48.5" 
        to="20,48.5 24.75,48.5 30,48.5"
        begin="0s;animation3.end;"
        dur="0.5s"
    />
```

The initial animation is triggered both by the beginning of time and the last animation finishing so it all repeats.

Comment: thanks, i tried finding if I could give 2 arguments for begin. But coulnt find anything, probably didn't use the right keywords.